# Control rendering/layer order of outputs from QGIS 3 Processing Modeler

Tags: qgis, layers, qgis-processing, qgis-3, draw-order

I'm using QGIS 3.0 model processor. I am trying to control the order in which the outputs render. Any ideas? I have tried to use parent algorithms but it seems to not make a difference. Is this a bug or an incorrect use of the parent algorithm function. Pictured are the outputs from my model. I want to have all the "A" files automatically draw on top of the others when the output from the model. [image]]

I've started trying to work with the code given by Kadir below and integrating it into the below hyperlink he provided. I have able to load in and work the example code. Now I am working on integrating Kadir's code into the model. I've included a snippet of the model below as well. 
https://anitagraser.com/2018/03/25/processing-script-template-for-qgis3/

[image]

Comment: Looks like currently the order is totally random https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/44184

Comment: Starting with QGIS 3.32, it is possible to reorder model output layers:
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/52996

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To move layers whose name start with "A" to top of the layer tree, use that code.

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
for layer in root.children():
    # you can change the condition
    if layer.name().startswith("A"):
        _layer = layer.clone()
        root.insertChildNode(0, _layer)
        root.removeChildNode(layer)
```

If you mean to order features in a layer, use "Order by Expression".
To order features by area, use that: (smaller polygons stay behind)

[image]

Comment: So I tried the expression $area, but all my features are points and lines and therefore don't really have an "area." Is there a different expression I can give them?

Comment: Do you want to control the order of layers or the order of features within one layer?

Comment: I realized I was not being clear and I got pulled away before I edited my comment. Yes Kadir want to control the order of the layers. I am editing my post now.

Comment: Kadir, do I incorporate this into the model by saving it as a script and adding it into my model? Does it matter which output it points to?

Comment: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/processing_python_scripts.html I found this tutorial for a earlier version of QGIS but it does not seem to be same process in 3.0

Comment: Processing for QGIS 3 refer to [Processing script template for QGIS3](https://anitagraser.com/2018/03/25/processing-script-template-for-qgis3/)

Comment: OK. I'm giving this a try and look into the python cook book and see if I can figure out the algorithm you gave me above into the example script. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Adding the code sample above to QGIS 2 processing script works but I've no idea for QGIS 3. Even if it's possible, I don't think It'll be as easy as QGIS 2.

Comment: Oh that would explain why I am getting errors. It did finally load. I think I just need to figure out where and how to input the code you previously gave me.

Comment: The way to writing processing script in QGIS 2 and QGIS 3 is extremely different.

Comment: I don't know if it is lucky or not that  QGIS 3 is my first dabble in QGIS then